# a shock/shock which one to be used

Tags: articles

> 1. A man suffering from ... shock should not be given anything to drink.
> 2. You'll get ... shock if you touch a live wire

What is the difference between the word 'shock' in the two sentences of which answer for

1. no article
2. a

Comment: This could be checked by looking up the usage in general reference: please see [definition 1.3 and 2 in the ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shock). #1 is a mass noun, and #2 is countable.

Answer (score 1):

The 'shock' in sentence 1 is an uncountable noun, whereas it  in sentence 2 is a countable one. 
In a general sense we use article *'a/an'* before singular countable nouns and *'no article'* before uncountable nouns and plural countable nouns.

> **[Shock](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shock_1)** : [uncountable] a medical condition in which you suddenly become very weak and cold and do not react normally,
>   especially after a serious accident or injury.
>
> *people suffering from shock*
>
> **[Shock](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shock_1)** :countable] a sudden flow of electricity that goes through your body that sometimes happens when you touch certain
>   objects.
>
> *You could get an electric shock if you touch it.*